# How can I navigate between 2 classes, one of them requires passing data? in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-web

I have 2 classes, one of them requires passing data, and class B does not have data for this class, for example, the login class passes the registration data to class A, but class B does not have this data, but it needs access to class A?

i used `Navigation.of(context).pushNamed(context, classB.id)`

but not work

Answer (score 8):

you can use `constructor` but in this case, whenever you use this class, you have to provide value, also you can make class value `nullable` and check it on build time. Another way is passing data by Route.

for more [navigate-with-arguments](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Here are some example:

**Passing data using ModalRoute**

```
  Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => WidgetA(),
                      settings: RouteSettings(
                        arguments: "Data for A",
                      )),
                );
```

**Receive Data**

```
class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  static final routeName = "/widgetA";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings;

    late String retriveString;

    if (data.arguments == null)
      retriveString = "empty";
    else
      retriveString = data.arguments as String;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Widget A"),
          Text("Got data from parent $retriveString"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Passing Emptydata using ModalRoute**

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => WidgetB(),
                  ),
                );
```

**On Receiver side**

```
class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {
  static final routeName = "/widgetB";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Widget B"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Passing data using Constructor**
must provide while using widget.

```
 Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => WidgetC(data: "for C"),
                  ),
                );
```

**Receiver**

```
class WidgetC extends StatelessWidget {
  final String data;

  const WidgetC({Key? key, required this.data}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [Text("Widget C "), Text("data using Constructor: $data")],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Passing data(optional) using Constructor**

```
Navigator.of(context).push(
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => WidgetD(),
                  ),
                );
```

**Receiver**

```
class WidgetD extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? data;

  WidgetD({Key? key, this.data = ""}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text("Widget D nullable "),
          Text("data using Constructor: $data")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot i solved it I created an object from the model and received the data in it and sent it to the class in the navigation

Comment: Didn't know that class() can be used inside navigator. Spent hours trying to capture arguments outside build :( thanks for this answer.

Comment: you can explore the attached link for more details