# How would I wrap the subtitle for the image url so that it leads to another screen?

Tags: image, flutter, gesturedetector, swiftui-ontapgesture

I am trying to allow a user to click on a picture and allow them to get information about that image, how would I go about that? I was thinking about wrapping the subtitle(with the image url) in the gesture detector and I was getting some errors so I would like to know how I could fix this error. Thank you

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  // This holds a list of fiction users
  // You can use data fetched from a database or a server as well
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allHerbs = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "plant1",
      "urlImage":
          'https://www.southernexposure.com/media/products/originals/sweet-genovese-basil-809aaf7e3d9a3f3fa7ce2f0eb4480e95.jpg'
    },
    {"id": 2, "name": "plant2", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 3, "name": "plant3", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 4, "name": "plant4", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 5, "name": "plant5", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 6, "name": "plant6", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 7, "name": "plant7", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 8, "name": "plant8", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 9, "name": "plant9", "urlImage": ''},
    {"id": 10, "name": "plant10", "urlImage": ''},
  ];

  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _foundHerbs = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    // at the beginning, all users are shown
    _foundHerbs = _allHerbs;
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = _allHerbs;
    } else {
      results = _allHerbs
          .where((user) =>
              user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _foundHerbs = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Herb Search'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _foundHerbs.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _foundHerbs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                        key: ValueKey(_foundHerbs[index]["id"]),
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        elevation: 4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Text(
                            _foundHerbs[index]["id"].toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_foundHerbs[index]['name']),
                          subtitle: Image.Network('${_foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"]} '),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text(
                      'No results found',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Inserting nonsense (or repeating yourself) to bypass the minimum text length requirement is a very bad idea, and violates site policies. Please do not do so in the future.

Comment: that wasn't the case I was trying to send the question without the repeated text and i got errors

Comment: And the reason why you got errors was because you didn't use enough text to describe the problem, and solving it by repeating yourself or adding noise is not the correct solution. The correct solution is to add more **appropriate content**, not noise or clutter. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account here (but you chose to ignore).

Comment: The first thing you should have  done when you wrote *I was getting some errors so I would like to know how I could fix this error* is to add the details about exactly what those *errors* are, including the **exact, complete error messages**. If you don't explain what the problem is that you're having, we can't help youi solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you don't need to use another widget to handle tap-event. `ListTile` already have  `onTap:` callback method.

Secondly, There are two issue on your`subtitle`,  `Image.Network` will be `Image.network` and providing path having extra space on url-part, or you can just use like`Image.network( _foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"],),`.

ListTile will be like

```dart
child: ListTile(
  onTap: () {
    print(_foundHerbs[index].toString());
  },
  leading: Text(
    _foundHerbs[index]["id"].toString(),
    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
  ),
  title: Text(_foundHerbs[index]['name']),
  subtitle: Container(
    color: Colors.amber,
    child: Image.network(
      '${_foundHerbs[index]["urlImage"]}',
    ),
  )),
```

Comment: this answer is excellent however , how would i allow the user to get to another page when they touch the picture

Comment: Seeing that I have an URL to load the picture, how would I connect the same picture to a new page using a different url

Comment: You can pass information through route,

Comment: could you please show me an example?

Comment: you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127)

Comment: Good day Sirs, I am trying to create a hyperlink to link each and every image's URL in my code so that a user can be directed to another page with information about the image that was clicked on. How do I go about doing that?. Thank you