# How to pass image from toggle button to next page in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter and i am trying out new things.my question is how to pass image from toggle button to next page in flutter?
This is the code for toggle button which have image and text in it,I want to pass selected image to next page

```
    Container(

   child:  SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: ToggleButtons(
          
          borderWidth: 1,
          
          children:<Widget> [
           
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
            child:
            CustomIcon(
              
             text:Text("TATA ACE",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 12),),
              image: Image.asset("images/delivery.png",scale: 9,),
              
              isSelected: isSelected[0],
              bgColor:const Color(0x000000),
            ),),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:10),
            child:
            CustomIcon(
             text: Text("TATA APE",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 12),),
              image: Image.asset("images/delivery.png",scale: 9,),
              
              isSelected: isSelected[1],
              bgColor: const Color(0x000000),
            ),),
```

CustomItem class is also defined below

```
class CustomIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  final Image image;
  final Text text;
  final bool isSelected;
  final Color bgColor;

  const CustomIcon(
      {Key? key,
      required this.text,
      required this.image,
      this.isSelected = false,
      this.bgColor = Colors.black, value1})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CustomIconState createState() => _CustomIconState();
}

class _CustomIconState extends State<CustomIcon> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Container(
      width: 105,
      height: 105,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: widget.isSelected
            ?  Colors.black : Colors.grey,shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
          Radius.circular(100),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          height: 105,
          width: 105,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.bgColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(100),
            ),
          ),
          child:Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              widget.image,
              
              widget.text,
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to pass this text and image to the next page or just image to next screen.

Comment: Can you include your `CustomIcon`?

Comment: I have added CustomIcon class above please check.

Comment: what are using for passing data to next page, constructor or route's arguments

Comment: can you suggest me the better way to pass the data to new page?

Comment: Both are ok based on your need, while using constructor you can force to have data on next page

Comment: I need example code to pass list of image using constructor to next page?

Comment: You can check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127)

Comment: you like to pass data on `CustomIcon` based on `ToggleButtons` selection?

Comment: Pass data on new page and customIcon class is togglebutton in my program and in toggle button i have image and i need to pass those images based on index or button clicked.