# Nullable class instance with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety

I have a class named `User` which basically has two variables. `name` and `age`. Also, I have another class named `UserList`.The aim of this class is to add the `user` objects to a list and return that list.

### User model

```
class User with ChangeNotifier{
    late String? name;
    late int? age;

  //set user name;
  setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
  }

  //set user age
  setAge(int age){
    this.age=age;
  }

}
```

### UserList class

```
class UserList with ChangeNotifier{
  final List<User> _list=[];

  //add a new user to the list.
  void addUserToList(User user){
  _list.add(user);
  notifyListeners();
  }
  //return the private list of users.
List<User>getUsers() =>_list;


}
```

Here is the scenario. I want to insert a value from one page and view that inserted value on the second page. Look at the pictures below. On the first page,

1. I insert the `age` and `name` values
2. Assign those values in a `User` object instance (`user.setName, user.setAge`)
3. Add that `user` object instance in a `UserList` list
4. Use `provider` to provide that list.(`Provider.of<UserList>(context).addUserToList(user);`

### First Page

[image: first pic]

### First Page Code

```
void main() {
  runApp(

      MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => UserList()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => User()),
          ],
          child: const MyApp())
  
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ageController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user =User();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
              TextField(
                controller: nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Name",
                ),
              ),
            TextField(
              controller: ageController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Age",
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){
             //providing userList
                user.setName(nameController.text); //setting user name
                user.setAge(int.parse(ageController.text)); // setting user age
               Provider.of<UserList>(context,listen: false).addUserToList(user); //providing the list of users
                nameController.text=""; //after insertion, clearing the text field
                ageController.text="";//after insertion, clearing the text field
                user=User(); // instantiating a new user object for the following insertion.
                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>const ViewUser()));
            }, child: const Text("Submit"))

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On the second page, display those inserted values in a `ListView`. Let's head to the main problem. Each item of `ListView`is wrapped with a `GestureDetector` to be able to gain functionality.I hope everything is clear up to now.
The problem is that; ***When I click on each item I want to return to the `first page`. But, this time the `TextField` shouldn't be empty. It must be replaced with the value of that item. For exmple. If I click on `John Nash` and `43`. The First page must pop up with field value of that list item.*** To be able to do that I use another `Provider` to provide `User` object. But, I couldn't do it because of null safety it gives an error about the user object is null. Is there any idea that could be helpful.

### Second Page

[image: second page]

### Second Page code

```
class ViewUser extends StatelessWidget {
  const ViewUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<User> userList = Provider.of<UserList>(context).getUsers();
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Users List"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          itemCount: userList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 15,),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    Provider.of<User>(context,listen: false)
                        .setName(userList[index].name!);
                    Provider.of<User>(context,listen: false)
                        .setAge(userList[index].age!);
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>MyHomePage()));
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50,
                    color: Colors.amber,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Text("Name: " + userList[index].name!),
                          const SizedBox(
                            width: 40,
                          ),
                          Text("Age:" + userList[index].age.toString()),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are using `Navigator.push` you can pass user as `arguments`.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    final user = userList[index];
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
          settings: RouteSettings(
            arguments: user,
          )),
    );
  },
```

`MyHomePage` build method will be

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    User user = User();
    User? args = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as User?;

    if (args != null) {
      nameController.text = args.name ?? "";
      ageController.text = args.age.toString();
    }
    return Scaffold(....
```

---

You can also use `Navigator.pop` in this case.

```dart
GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
    final user = userList[index];
    Navigator.pop(context, user);
  },
```

And to receive data on `MyHomePage`

```dart
onPressed: () async {
//....
final data = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => const ViewUser(),
  ),
);
if (data != null) {
  nameController.text = data.name ?? "";
  ageController.text = data.age.toString();
}
```

More about [navigate-with-arguments](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

Comment: Thank you much I have been looking for this answer for a week

Comment: You can also use `constructor`, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127)

Comment: Thank you but, when I implement a constructor I have to supply a user object each time.

Comment: you can use nullable user and check on build time like the way i did on arguments

Comment: I want to ask this question. I get the data on the first page. But now., when I edit the text field and save it, it creates a new list item on the second page. This isn't what I want. I want to overwrite the item on the second page. I couldn't think of a way to do it. Can you help me with that?

Comment: in that case , you can look for how to update data and include another field that will be your unique id

Comment: I am planning to pass multiple arguments to the first page such that the "user" and the "index" of the list. Now, since I have the index. I could replace it with that value? Does it sound like a good plan to you?

Comment: You can do that too, feel free to create separate question if you face any issue,  including the efforts you put to solve the issue.