# How to pass parameters through navigation in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation

I need to pass a id parameter to a separate page while navigating from one page to another, I am currently using named routes to navigate but they are not letting me pass parameters.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127)

Comment: You can review the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "final" variable in the second route class and pass the values during instantiation of that class' object.

The below navigation example was obtained from [Flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) I just added the "passing data to a new page" process.

```
class FirstRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("First Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Open route"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      const SecondRoute(text: "This is the text")),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(text);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: const Text("Go back!"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```