# How do I display the output of a method from the first page on a second page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

The app is supposed to take in the first name on the first page and reverse it, then print the output on the second page. I'm having trouble implementing the output from the _incrementCounter method into the SecondScreen class in order to print the output on the second page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctxt) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FirstScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  String t1 = '', output = '';
  RevName name = RevName();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      output = name.reverseName(t1) as String;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text("Reverse Name")),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: TextField(keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Enter Your First Name',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                onChanged: (text) {
                  t1 = text;
                },
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
                  );
                  _incrementCounter();
                },
                child: Text('Reverse Name'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }

  void setState(Null Function() param0) {}
}
```

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Reverse Name"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
          Center(
              child: OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('Back')
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The class where name is being reversed and returning the reversed name

```
class RevName {
  String name, reversed;

  RevName({this.name = '', this.reversed = ''});

  String reverseName(name) {
    reversed = name.split('').reversed.join('');
    return '$reversed';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've `RevName` model class, to store name and reverse name. You can modify like,

```dart
class RevName {
  String name, reversed;

  RevName({
    required this.name,
  }) : reversed = name.split('').reversed.join('');
}
```

Now let's pass data using constructor. Remove state `RevName` and follow this,

```dart
child: OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    RevName revName = RevName(name: t1);
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SecondScreen(
          data: revName,
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
  child: const Text('Reverse Name'),
),
```

On receiver side `SecondScreen`.

```dart
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final RevName data;
  const SecondScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.data,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Reverse Name"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Text(data.name),
            Text(data.reversed),
```

You can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127) to explore alternative way.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for clarifying that for me.

Comment: Glad to help you out. You can check [this] for alternative ways.