# How to pass a variable (TextEditingController) to another class

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

> class that i have the variable in

```
...
class _ActivitiesParticipantsState extends State<ActivitiesParticipants> {
  final activityController = TextEditingController();
  
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  //Activities participants
  List<String> docIDs = [];

  //get docIDS
  Future getDocId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection(
          activityController.text.trim(),
        )
        .get()
        .then(
          (snapshot) => snapshot.docs.forEach(
            (element) {
              docIDs.add(element.reference.id);
            },
          ),
        );
    //stuff
  }

 
  @override
  void dispose() {
    activityController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
     
              TextFormField(
                controller: activityController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'e',
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  

                  setState(
                    () {
                      getDocId();
                    },
                  );
                },
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                    20,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.deepPurple,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Test',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: wee(),
                      //docIDs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                          child: ListTile(
                            dense: true,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                            tileColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 235, 235, 235),
                            title: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 5,
                                  ),
                                  Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    child: Title(
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      child: InterestedName(
                                          documentID: docIDs[index]),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 20,
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),

                           
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

...
How do I get the variable "activityController" to another class?
This other class is used to get Text to fill the ListTile

> class that I want to get the variable

```
  final String documentID;

  InterestedName({required this.documentID});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // get the collection
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Project Koalas [test]');

    return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      future: users.doc(documentID).get(),
      builder: ((context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(
            'Name: ${data['name']}',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                fontFamily: 'Quicksand',
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          );
        }

        return Text('loading...');
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

I would like to get the variable to be able to get the collection name that I want to take data from, as the collection I would like to take from is dependent on the user's choice.
If there is any way else to somehow fill the List tile in the same class, please let me know how.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: If you are changing route, you pass it though constructor or route arguments

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68605567/10157127) where I;ve showed different ways of doing it