# How to linked facilities of each element in a list flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter,I ran into a problem,i got problem where i cant linked facilites_list_screen to facilties_details_screen.dart using flutter when user click the picture in facilites_list_screen it will goes to fecilities_details.dart

//this is homepage for facilies_list_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/model/facilities.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/screen/facilities_details_screen.dart';

class FacilitiesListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  FacilitiesListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  _FacilitiesListScreenState createState() => _FacilitiesListScreenState();
}

class _FacilitiesListScreenState extends State<FacilitiesListScreen> {
  final TextStyle dropdownMenuItem =
      TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 18);

  final primary = Color.fromARGB(255, 206, 84, 84);
  final secondary = Color(0xfff29a94);

  final List<Map> facilitiesListMap = [
    {
      "name": "Badminton Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/badminton.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "PingPong Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/pinpong.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "Futsal Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Indoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/futsal.jpg?alt=media"
    },
    {
      "name": "Tennis Court",
      "location": "UTM Convention Hall",
      "type": "Outdoor Courts",
      "logoText":
          "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/tennis.jpg?alt=media"
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xfff0f0f0),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 145),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: facilitiesList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        Facilities facilities = facilitiesList[index];
                        return buildList(context, index);
                      })),
              Container(
                height: 140,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: primary,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(30))),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.menu,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "List of Facilities",
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.filter_list,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 110,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                      child: Material(
                        elevation: 5.0,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                        child: TextField(
                          // controller: TextEditingController(text: locations[0]),
                          cursorColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          style: dropdownMenuItem,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "Search Facilities",
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black38, fontSize: 16),
                              prefixIcon: Material(
                                elevation: 0.0,
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30)),
                                child: Icon(Icons.search),
                              ),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  horizontal: 25, vertical: 13)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 110,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              border: Border.all(width: 3, color: secondary),
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(facilitiesListMap[index]['logoText']),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  facilitiesListMap[index]['name'],
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: primary,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 18),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.location_on,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(facilitiesListMap[index]['location'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 6,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.sports_tennis,
                      color: secondary,
                      size: 20,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 5,
                    ),
                    Text(facilitiesListMap[index]['type'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: primary, fontSize: 13, letterSpacing: .3)),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

this is homepage facilites_details_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/main.dart';
import 'package:oracle_diamond_02/model/facilities.dart';

class FacilitiesDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Facilities facilities;

  FacilitiesDetailsScreen(this.facilities);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              foregroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black26),
              height: 400,
              child: Image.network(facilities.ImageUrl, fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                const SizedBox(height: 250),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                      child: Text(
                        facilities.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 28.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        vertical: 8.0,
                        horizontal: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    IconButton(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          child: Text(
                            "Reserve Now",
                            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (_) => BookingCalendarDemoApp()));
                          },
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 30.0),
                      Text(
                        facilities.name.toUpperCase(),
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          facilities.description,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 16.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              elevation: 0,
              centerTitle: true,
              title: Text(
                "List of Facilities",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---

this is homepage facilities.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Facilities {
  String name;
  String description;
  String ImageUrl;

  Facilities(
      {required this.name, required this.description, required this.ImageUrl});
}

List<Facilities> facilitiesList = [
  Facilities(
      name: 'Badminton Court',
      description:
          'Badminton Courts are the rectangular surfaces used for the racket sport of badminton. divided in half by a center badminton net, courts are usually marked for both singles or doubles games with boundary widths varying between the two match types',
      ImageUrl:
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/badminton.jpg?alt=media'),
  Facilities(
      name: 'Tennis Court',
      description:
          'Table tennis, also known as ping-pong and whiff-whaff, is a sport in which two or four players hit a lightweight ball, also known as the ping-pong ball, back and forth across a table using small rackets. The game takes place on a hard table divided by a net.',
      ImageUrl:
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/tennis.jpg?alt=media'),
  Facilities(
      name: 'PingPong Court',
      description:
          'Table tennis, also known as ping-pong and whiff-whaff, is a sport in which two or four players hit a lightweight ball, also known as the ping-pong ball, back and forth across a table using small rackets. The game takes place on a hard table divided by a net.',
      ImageUrl:
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/pinpong.jpg?alt=media'),
  Facilities(
      name: 'Futsal Court',
      description:
          'Futsal is an association football-based game playedon a hard court smaller than a football pitch, and mainly indoors. It has similarities to five-a-sidefootball and indoor soccer.',
      ImageUrl:
          'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/oracle-diamond-02.appspot.com/o/futsal.jpg?alt=media'),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your listView item with tappable widget like `GestureDetector`/InkWell, and then use navigator like

```dart
Widget buildList(BuildContext context, int index) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => FacilitiesDetailsScreen( facilitiesList[index]),
      ));
    },
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
```

Comment: where do i put this code? in which file?

Comment: On your `buildList` method that is inside  `FacilitiesListScreen`

Comment: Glad to help, if you like to explore more about passing data, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127) and [navigation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)