# Provider does not read it

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, changenotifier

I want to use the _count variable in another widget.
I can't access _count variable with provider

```
class Hamburger extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hamburger({super.key});

  @override
  State<Hamburger> createState() => _HamburgerState();
}

class _HamburgerState extends State<Hamburger> {
  int _count = 1;
```

Comment: can you include more details

Comment: I want to use the _count variable in another widget.
I can't access _count variable with provider

Comment: you can pass the value trough constructor.

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127 may help you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to access _count in a separate class without providing context to the Provider. To access the value of _count using Provider, you need to wrap the _HamburgerState widget in a ChangeNotifierProvider and expose _count as a listenable property.

This is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Hamburger extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hamburger({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hamburger> createState() => _HamburgerState();
}

class _HamburgerState extends State<Hamburger> {
  int _count = 1;

  void incrementCount() {
    setState(() {
      _count++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: this,
      child: Container(),
    );
  }
}

class CountNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _count;

  int get count => _count;

  set count(int value) {
    _count = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: @override
Widget build(Buildcontext context){
Color coloricon = Provider.of<iconcolor>(context).coloricon;
return ChangeNotifierProvider.value()
}
}
'_HamburgerState' doesn't conform to the bound 'ChangeNotifier?' of the type parameter 'T'.
Try using a type that is or is a subclass of 'ChangeNotifier?'.