# The named parameter 'title' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter, dart

So I face an error when using `webview_flutter` and I am not sure how to fix it:

In my `Page.dart` I have the below `onTap` actions:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, WebView.routeName,
   arguments:
      MyPageArguments("Page Title1", "https://example1.com"));
    
Navigator.pushNamed(context, WebView.routeName,
   arguments:
      MyPageArguments("Page Title2", "https://example2.com"));

class MyPageArguments {
  final String title;
  final String url;
  MyPageArguments(this.title, this.url);
}
```

Then in my WebView.dart I do the following:

```
class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/myRoute';
  final String title;
  final String url;

  const WebView({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
    required this.url,
  });

  @override
  _WebViewState createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView> {
     //Remaining code
}
```

And in my main.dart I try to define the route:

```
  '/myRoute': (context) => WebView(),
```

But I get the following error:

`The named parameter 'title' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. (Documentation)`

`Try adding the required argument.`

So I should do something like the example below, however I am not sure how to pass the dynamic `title` and `url` parameters to `main.dart`:

```
'/myRoute': (context) => WebView(title: "Page Title1", url: "https://example1.com"),
```

Comment: You need to pass the parameters through the route, check at this article: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Comment: Hi, this is exactly the resource I was looking at but for some reason I get the mentioned error and I can't figure out why. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While you are already using route arguments, you can remove `WebView` 's constructor parameters or make them option(with nullable dataType).

Your `WebView` state class will access the route arguments.

```dart
class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/myRoute';
  const WebView({super.key});
  @override
  _WebViewState createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final routeArguments = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as MyPageArguments?;

    final url = routeArguments?.url;
    final title = routeArguments?.title;
    return SizedBox();
  }
}
```

You can check my another [answer with more example code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68605773/10157127)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **onGenerateRoute** in **MaterialApp**

```
Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
switch (settings.name) {
  case WebView.routeName:
    return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings, builder: (_) => const WebView(
          args: settings.arguments as MyPageArguments
        ))
        }}
```

in **WebView** you should declare MyPageArguments

```
final MyPageArguments args;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).